Vaadin : Custom Login Form - Why isn't my form being submitted to the action endpoint?
I am trying to make a custom login form using Vaadin V24.4.11 as described in this answer as it is being referenced in many Vaadin forum posts.
I would like to delegate the authentication process to Spring Security.
My issue is that when I click on the submit button, nothing happens, my form is not being submitted to the login endpoint. When I check with debugging tools, I only see a click event being raised :
Click event
Could anyone help me understand/find a solution ?
I developed my own form as follows :
@Tag("form")
public class HtmlLoginForm extends HtmlContainer implements HasComponents {
  /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  
  private EmailField emailField;
  private PasswordField passwordField;
  private TextField secondFactorField;
  private Checkbox rememberMeCheckbox;
  private Button resetPasswordLink;
  private Span errorMessage;
  private Button submitButton;
  
  boolean enableRememberMe, enableSecondFactor;
  
  /**
   * Default constructor - Basic login form : No remember me checkbox, No second factor text field
   */
  public HtmlLoginForm() {
    add(init(false, false, null));
  }
  /**
   * Enhanced constructor - Lets developer decide if remember me checkbox and/or second factor field are enabled
   * @param enableRememberMe adds remember me checkbox if true
   * @param enableSecondFactor adds second factor text field if true
   */
  public HtmlLoginForm(boolean enableRememberMe, boolean enableSecondFactor, ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent<Button>> listener) {
    add(init(enableRememberMe, enableSecondFactor, listener));
  }
  /**
   * Initializer for the login form components
   * 
   * @param enableRememberMe adds remember me checkbox if true
   * @param enableSecondFactor adds second factor text field if true
   * @return Layout containing form components
   */
  private VerticalLayout init(boolean enableRememberMe, boolean enableSecondFactor, ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent<Button>> listener) {
    setId("loginForm");
    
    this.enableRememberMe = enableRememberMe;
    this.enableSecondFactor = enableSecondFactor;
    
    emailField = new EmailField("Email");
    passwordField = new PasswordField("Password");
    resetPasswordLink = new Button("Reset my password");
    errorMessage = new Span();
    submitButton = new Button("Log in/Sign up");
    
    emailField.setRequired(true);
    emailField.setRequiredIndicatorVisible(true);
    
    emailField.setId("username");
    emailField.getElement().setAttribute("name", "username");
    
    passwordField.setRequired(true);
    passwordField.setRequiredIndicatorVisible(true);
    
    passwordField.setId("password");
    passwordField.getElement().setAttribute("name", "password");
    
    resetPasswordLink.setEnabled(false);
    resetPasswordLink.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY_INLINE);
    
    submitButton.setEnabled(false);
    submitButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
    if(listener != null) { 
      submitButton.addClickListener(listener);
    }
    
    getElement().setAttribute("method", "POST");
    getElement().setAttribute("action", "login");
    
    return buildForm(enableRememberMe, enableSecondFactor);
  }
  /**
   * Builds the layout containing the login form components
   * @param enableRememberMe adds remember me checkbox if true
   * @param enableSecondFactor adds second factor text field if true
   * @return VerticalLayout with all components added
   */
  private VerticalLayout buildForm(boolean enableRememberMe, boolean enableSecondFactor) {
    VerticalLayout formLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    
    formLayout.setSpacing(false);
    formLayout.add(emailField, passwordField);
    if(enableSecondFactor) {
      secondFactorField = new TextField("Second factor token");
      secondFactorField.setVisible(false);
      secondFactorField.setRequiredIndicatorVisible(true);
      formLayout.add(secondFactorField);
    }
    if(enableRememberMe) {
      rememberMeCheckbox = new Checkbox("Remember me");
      rememberMeCheckbox.getElement().setAttribute("name", "remember-me");
      formLayout.add(rememberMeCheckbox);
    }
    formLayout.add(resetPasswordLink, errorMessage, submitButton);
    
    formLayout.setHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER, formLayout.getChildren().toArray(Component[]::new));
    
    return formLayout;
  }
  /**
   * Overrides the default submit button click listener
   * @param listener
   */
  public void setSubmitButtonClickListener(ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent<Button>> listener) {
    submitButton.addClickListener(listener);
  }
  
  public void prepareForSecondFactor() {
    emailField.setEnabled(false);
    passwordField.setEnabled(false);
    secondFactorField.setVisible(true);
  }
  
  public void setResetPasswordClickListener(DomEventListener listener) {
    resetPasswordLink.getElement().addEventListener("click", listener);
  }
  
  public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage.setText(errorMessage);
  }
}

That form is embedded in a View :
@Route(value = "login", layout = MainLayout.class)
@AnonymousAllowed
public class LoginView extends BrowserTimezoneAwareVerticalLayout implements HasDynamicTitle {
  /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Autowired
  private ViewsConfigurationHelper viewsConfHelper;
  
  @Autowired
  private AppUserService userService;
  @Autowired
  private ResetPasswordService resetPasswordService;

  private HtmlLoginForm loginForm = new HtmlLoginForm();
  
  public LoginView() {
    addClassName("login-view");
    setSizeFull(); 
    setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
    setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);
    
    loginForm.getEmailField().addValueChangeListener(event -> {
      if(userService.emailExists(event.getValue())) {
        loginForm.getResetPasswordLink().setEnabled(true);
        loginForm.getSubmitButton().setText("Log in");
        loginForm.getSubmitButton().setEnabled(true);
        loginForm.getSubmitButton().getElement().setAttribute("on-click", "submit");
      } else {
        loginForm.getResetPasswordLink().setEnabled(false);
        loginForm.getSubmitButton().setText("Sign up");
        loginForm.getSubmitButton().setEnabled(true);
        loginForm.getSubmitButton().addClickListener(this::signupHandler);
        loginForm.getSubmitButton().getElement().removeAttribute("on-click");
      }
    });
    loginForm.getResetPasswordLink().addClickListener(this::forgotPasswordHandler);
    setHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER, loginForm);
    
    setSpacing(false);
    add(loginForm);
  }
  
  private void signupHandler(ClickEvent<Button> event) {
    String username = loginForm.getEmailField().getValue();
    if (!username.isBlank() && !username.isEmpty()) {
      UI.getCurrent().navigate(SignupView.class, username);
    } else {
      NotificationHelper.showError("Veuillez renseigner votre email");
    }
  }
  
  private void forgotPasswordHandler(ClickEvent<Button> event) {
    String username = loginForm.getEmailField().getValue();
    boolean resetPassword = !loginForm.getEmailField().isInvalid() && !username.isBlank() && !username.isEmpty();
    if (resetPassword) {
      resetPassword(username);
    } else {
      NotificationHelper.showError("Veuillez renseigner votre email");
    }
  }
  
  private void resetPassword(String email) {
    try {
      resetPasswordService.sendResetPasswordEmail(email, getBrowserTimezone());
      NotificationHelper.showSuccess("Email successfully sent to " + email);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      NotificationHelper.showUnexpectedError();
    } catch(NotFoundException nfe) {
      log.error(nfe.getMessage(), nfe);
      NotificationHelper.showError(nfe.getMessage());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String getPageTitle() {
    return viewsConfHelper.getLocaleViewTitle(this.getClass());
  }
}

Thanks in advance for your time and help !

I don't think you can add click listeners like this:
loginForm.getSubmitButton().getElement().setAttribute("on-click", "submit");

Check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76762655/8962195
